# How likely are experimental components such as ExposedDropdownMenuBox to break?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The Jetpack Compose API contains some experimental components like the `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`. I'm considering to use it in my desktop application, so I was wondering how likely it is that those experimental components get removed or break?

Has this happened before with other components or can we expect rather *minor* changes, but overall the componets will not cause much trouble in future and it's *safe* to use them?

Comment: I think you can safely use them, although they are marked as experimental. Still, they are almost stable, I am using such experimental components in my application, which I published to Play Store, and I don't see any problem with them. I don't expect them to receive big changes, but minor changes are expected. For more safety, use a stable version of Jetpack Compose, not an alpha or beta version.